A paradox regarding the work done on spring and its change in mechanical energy if elongated
Lets consider a massless spring

After it is elongated the external forces must be equal (since their sum is equal to ma which is 0 as m is 0), the external work done on the spring as derived in the diagram (the wall does no work as the point of application is fixed) is + $\frac 12 k x^2$.
Since external work changes mechanical energy and a massless spring cannot have kinetic energy, so this external work changes the potential energy of the spring by $\frac 12 k x^2$.
Now here the contradiction arises, probably due to my incomplete knowledge. By work-energy theorem, net work on spring is change in its kinetic energy. But a massless spring has 0 change in kinetic energy as final and initial kinetic energies are 0 so net work on spring is zero.
So what are the forces that are doing work, the wall does no work, the force by us (remember we extended the spring), $kx$, does $\frac12 k x^2$ work on the spring and there must be some internal force in the spring. So
$$W_{ext} + W_{int} = 0, W_{ext} = -W_{int}, \frac12 k x^2 = -W_{int}.$$
I just want a confirmation that what I am thinking is true and that there is some kind of internal force in the spring that is doing negative work though it is not mentioned in my textbook. Could you please assure me that there is?

The net work done on an object is equal to its change in kinetic energy for a rigid body, i.e. a body that does not store energy. A spring is not a rigid body. It stores energy.  The net work done on a deformable body is equal to its change in kinetic energy plus its change in stored energy.

@looksquirrel101 that depends on the specific author. Some authors use a work energy theorem that applies to all bodies including deformable bodies. Others use a version that applies to point particles. I would say rather few use a version specific to extended rigid bodies.

@Dale - Any author that derives a work-energy theorem for deformable bodies would find that the work done on the body is equal to the change in kinetic energy plus the change in stored energy.

@looksquirrel101 the work energy theorem for deformable bodies typically says that the change in center of mass KE is equal to the net work where the net work is not the total work done on the body but the net force times the displacement of the center of mass. But again, different authors treat this differently. Claims that “any author” does it one way or another are incorrect

@Dale. Your claim is again incorrect. The work done on a deformable body is not simply the net force times the displacement of the COM. Such a statement does not account for the stored energy in the body. A spring displaced outward equally on both ends is a simple counter example to your claim.

@looksquirrel101 said “The work done on a deformable body is not simply the net force times the displacement of the COM”. But the net work is defined thus by some authors

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


By work energy theorem, net work on spring is change in its kinetic energy. But a massless spring has 0 change in kinetic energy as final and initial kinetic energies are 0 so net work on spring is zero

This is correct, however it is frequently misunderstood. I would guess that the work energy theorem is the most confusing topic in typical introductory physics classes. Note, different authors have different approaches to this topic (adding to the confusion), so if you are being graded on this material it is important to learn what your specific textbook author and your professor intend on this topic!
The "net work" in the work energy theorem is not the total work done by external forces. The word "net" refers to the "net force", not "total work". The net work is specifically $$W_{net}=\vec F_{net} \cdot \vec {\Delta x}_{CoM}$$ Where $\vec{\Delta x}_{CoM}$ is the displacement of the center of mass. Since for the massless spring $\vec F_{net}=0$ we immediately get $W_{net}=0$.
Indeed, the force on the right hand side of the spring does positive work on the spring, and the force on the left hand side of the spring does no work on the spring. So the total work, the sum of the work done by each force, is non-zero. $$W_{total}=\sum_i \left( \vec F_i \cdot \vec{\Delta x}_i \right)$$
Since $W_{total}>0$, and since by the work energy theorem $\Delta KE = W_{net}=0$, we know that all of the work $W_{total}$ went in to changing potential energy.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Previously I said the work energy theorem is not applicable to the spring, but in fact it can be applied if we treat the details with care and remember to include all forms of energy as per the energy conservation principle.  The work energy theorem can be stated as:
$$Work_{net} = \Delta KE  .$$
The net work is not simply $F \Delta X$, but is composed of all forms of changes in energy that might be involved. We can rewrite the work energy theorem as :
$$(F_{total} \Delta x - \Delta PE - \Delta HE) = \Delta KE  ,$$
where PE is potential energy and HE is heat energy (perhaps due to friction). Sometimes there are other forms of energy involved that have to be subtracted from the total work to obtain the net work but for simplicity I have not included all of them here. In the case of the stretched spring, the initial and final velocity is zero and we can write the above equation as:
$$(F_{total} \Delta x - \Delta PE ) = 0,$$
$$\implies  F_{total} \Delta x = \Delta PE  $$
$$\implies  F_{total} \Delta x = 1/2 \ k x^2  $$
$$\implies  \text{Work}_{total} = 1/2 \ k x^2  $$
Similarly for the case of raising an object in a gravitational field the result is:
$$  \text{Work}_{total} = mgh  $$
In other words, all the work input in the case of the spring and raising an object has been converted to potential energy. Potential energy is just stored energy. When we raise an object in a gravitational field it has the potential to do work when we release the object. When we stretch a spring it also gains potential energy because it can do work when we release the spring.

So you are saying that the work energy theorem is not applicable here as it does not apply to where work is not being converted to kinetic energy? That still leaves a doubt. If you pick up something from ground, it final velocity is 0, initally it was 0, and we usually use the work energy theorem to say(consider system earth+object) that work done by us +work done by gravity =0 , so work done by us = mgh, and work by us is the external work, so its the change in PE, so mgh is change in PE . But since you say that theorem is not applicable here then how will you calculate the change in PE then?

@KhushivBatra I am just saying that the work energy theorem in its over specific form ($\text{Work} = F_{total} \Delta x = \Delta KE$) is sometime not applicable. In the example you give in your comment we would have the simplistic form $\text{Work}= \Delta KE \implies mgh = 0$ which is obviously not correct when h >0. In the more detailed full form we would have $\text{Work}{total} = F{total} \Delta x = \Delta KE + \Delta PE + \Delta HE$,  $\implies \text{Work}{total} = F{total} h = 0 + \Delta PE + 0$,  $ \implies  \text{Work}_{total} =  \Delta PE = mgh$.

As long as you use the broader energy conservation principle and consider all forms of energy involved, everything works out fine.

@KhushivBatra  My previous answer might have been a little misleading, so I have re-written it. The work energy theorem is applicable in the spring scenario and the gravity scenario, but you have to apply it carefully, taking all forms of energy into consideration.


So what are the forces that are doing work,

The applied external force at the free end of the spring does positive work of $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ since its force is in the same direction as the displacement of the spring. However, at the same time the spring does negative work of $-\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ since the restoring force of the spring is in the opposite direction of the displacement of the spring. Thus the net work done on the spring is zero making the change in KE zero per the work energy theorem.
In effect the spring in doing negative work takes the energy the external force transferred to the spring and stores it as elastic potential energy in the spring.

I just want a confirmation that what I am thinking is true and that
there is some kind of internal force in the spring that is doing
negative work though it is not mentioned in my textbook. Could you
please assure me that there is?

I can assure you that the spring force is doing negative work.
In order for a change in  potential energy to occur, work must be done by what is called a "conservative force". The force in an elastic spring is a conservative force. Other examples of conservative forces are the gravitational force and the electrostatic force between electric charges. The work done by a conservative force, $W_{c}$,  equals the negative of the change in potential energy resulting from the work, or
$$W_{c}=-\Delta U$$
So we see that if $\Delta U$ is positive, as in the case of the stretched spring, the work done by the conservative force must be negative.
Hope this helps.

This is incorrect. The net work done on the spring is certainly not zero if it is being stretched.

@looksquirrel101 The net work is zero. The net work doesn't equal the change in elastic potential energy. The work done by the spring is negative. The spring force is conservative which means the work done by the spring equals the negative of its elastic potential energy

It has nothing to do with quasistatic. The end of the spring begins and ends at rest. if there were a mass attached, its change in KE would be zero.

@Proscionexium - No, if one side of the spring is fixed then the work done on the spring is the integrated force on the opposite side times the increments of deflection of the spring.  This is never zero for any non-zero force on a deformable spring.

@BobD - No, the net work done on the spring is the integral of the force applied to the spring times the incremental deflection of the spring.  This is not zero.

You are confusing the work done on the spring with the work done by the spring. The work done on the spring is positive.

@looksquirrel101 the work done on the spring by the force at the free end is positive because the direction of the force is the same as the direction of the displacement. But the spring does an equal amount of negative work because its force is opposite to the displacement of the spring. Thus the NET work is zero. It is analogous to lifting a mass at rest on the ground to rest at a height h. The lifting force (you) does positive work mgh while gravity does an equal amount of negative work -mgh for a net work of zero and change in KE of zero

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For both the gravity and spring the work done by the external agent wind up stored at potential energy

Please see my comment in chat.

@looksquirrel101, Could you add your own answer to explain what differences(your arguments) you have with the answers of others and how does that explain the original question. It is getting really confusing for me now.

@KhushivBatra you need to focus on what your specific textbook author says. BobD’s statements are consistent with some authors, looksquirell101 is consistent with fewer.  But for your class and your grade you need to follow your professor’s approach (even if it differs from all of these presented here)

@KhushivBatra I think you should un accept my answer and accept Dale's answer instead as his is most applicable to the case of a massless spring. See my discussions with him under his post.

@KhushivBatra The answer given by KDP below is correct. It's similar to what I would have written.
